# Regex in Swift, having loads of trouble getting it to work

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I'm very new to swift and trying to use a regex to match a credit card number. From what I've gathered, regular expressions aren't at all straight forward in swift and I've had a lot of trouble getting this block of code to compile let alone return anything useful.

```
var info : String = ""

    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "/d{4}/s/d{6}/s/d{5}", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)

    for (var i : UInt = 0; i < cardsInTable.count; i++) {
        let line : NSString = cardsInTable.elementBoundByIndex(i).label

        let matches = regex.numberOfMatchesInString("-v", options:NSMatchingOptions.WithTransparentBounds, range: NSRangeFromString(line as String))
        if (matches > 0) {
            info += (line as String) + "\n"
        }
    }
```

I'm attempting to just match line to "/d{4}/s/d{6}/s/d{5}" (4 digit, space, 6 digit, space, 5 digit) but keep getting this error when running the code:

```
caught "NSRangeException", "*** -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: Range or index out of bounds"
```

Comment: You are passing the fixed string `"-v"` as the first argument to the function, but the length of `line` as length ...

Answer (score 3):

Your slashes are in the wrong direction. You need backslashes not forward slashes.

```
"\\d{4}\\s\\d{6}\\s\\d{5}"
```

---

Fixing three problems… bad regex, wrong string passed to regex, and wrong range, here is what I have.

```
var info : String = ""

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\d{4}\\s\\d{6}\\s\\d{5}", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)

for (var i : Int = 0; i < cardsInTable.count; i++) {
    let line : NSString = cardsInTable[i].label
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: line.length)

    let matches = regex.numberOfMatchesInString(line as String, options:[.WithTransparentBounds], range: range)
    if (matches > 0) {
        info += (line as String) + "\n"
    }
}
```

Comment: O geez. And in swift the backslashes need to be escaped like this correct: "\\d{4}\\s\\d{6}\\s\\d{5}"

Comment: But the back-slashes need to be escaped. `"\\d{4}\\s\\d{6}\\s\\d{5}"`

Comment: Sorry for the think-o. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Actually there is no such thing as a "forward slash", it is just a "slash", the unicode name is: "SOLIDUS". The "forward slash" came about because Windows users were calling "\" slash.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Still having some trouble getting the desired results. Would any of the options: I previously selected conflict with finding digits? Would you reccomend any others?

Comment: @AlexSchade I don't know what number pattern you are trying to match. Add a text description of the pattern with sample matching and failing input.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the wrong pattern, this line

```
let matches = regex.numberOfMatchesInString("-v", 
       options:NSMatchingOptions.WithTransparentBounds,
       range: NSRangeFromString(line as String))
```

is completely wrong. The first argument should be the given line,
not the fixed string `"-v"`. And `NSRangeFromString()` does not what
you might think it does. It creates a range from a *textual representation*. E.g.

```
NSRangeFromString("1234 123456 12345")
```

creates the range `(1234,123456)`. This is what causes the
*"Range or index out of bounds"*
exception.

Correct would be

```
let matches = regex.numberOfMatchesInString(line as String,
    options: [],
    range: NSMakeRange(0, line.length))
```

(with an empty option set because I don't think that the `.WithTransparentBounds` option is actually needed here).

Comment: Ah Foo, you beat me too it. I just noticed the `NSRangeFromString` error.

Comment: Is there a way to specify no option? Nil isn't a valid type for NSMatchingOptions

Comment: @AlexSchade: Yes, as `[]`.

Comment: @AlexSchade: Yes, because the last group has 4 digits and your pattern required 5 digits. What did you expect?

Comment: Sorry for the mistype. Now working. I appreciate the help.